# Waiting on a condition (pthread_cond_wait) and a socket change (select) simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, asyncsocket

I'm writing a POSIX compatible multi-threaded server in c/c++ that must be able to accept, read from, and write to a large number of connections asynchronously.  The server has several worker threads which perform tasks and occasionally (and unpredictably) queue data to be written to the sockets.  Data is also occasionally (and unpredictably) written to the sockets by the clients, so the server must also read asynchronously.  One obvious way of doing this is to give each connection a thread which reads and writes from/to its socket; this is ugly, though, since each connection may persist for a long time and the server thus may have to hold hundred or thousand threads just to keep track of connections.

A better approach would be to have a single thread that handled all communications using the select()/pselect() functions.  I.e., a single thread waits on any socket to be readable, then spawns a job to process the input that will be handled by a pool of other threads whenever input is available.  Whenever the other worker threads produce output for a connection, it gets queued, and the communication thread waits for that socket to be writable before writing it.

The problem with this is that the communication thread may be waiting in the select() or pselect() function when output is queued by the worker threads of the server.  It's possible that, if no input arrives for several seconds or minutes, a queued chunk of output will just wait for the communication thread to be done select()ing.  This shouldn't happen, however--data should be written as soon as possible.

Right now I see a couple solutions to this that are thread-safe.  One is to have the communication thread busy-wait on input and update the list of sockets it waits on for writing every tenth of a second or so.  This isn't optimal since it involves busy-waiting, but it will work.  Another option is to use pselect() and send the USR1 signal (or something equivalent) whenever new output has been queued, allowing the communication thread to update the list of sockets it is waiting on for writable status immediately.  I prefer the latter here, but still dislike using a signal for something that should be a condition (pthread_cond_t).  Yet another option would be to include, in the list of file descriptors on which select() is waiting, a dummy file that we write a single byte to whenever a socket needs to be added to the writable fd_set for select(); this would wake up the communications server because that particular dummy file would then be readable, thus allowing the communications thread to immediately update it's writable fd_set.

I feel intuitively, that the second approach (with the signal) is the 'most correct' way to program the server, but I'm curious if anyone knows either which of the above is the most efficient, generally speaking, whether either of the above will cause race conditions that I'm not aware of, or if anyone knows of a more general solution to this problem.  What I really want is a pthread_cond_wait_and_select() function that allows the comm thread to wait on both a change in sockets or a signal from a condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem.

One often used solution is to have pipes as a communication mechanism from worker threads back to the I/O thread. Having completed its task a worker thread writes the pointer to the result into the pipe. The I/O thread waits on the read end of the pipe along with other sockets and file descriptors and once the pipe is ready for read it wakes up, retrieves the pointer to the result and proceeds with pushing the result into the client connection in non-blocking mode.

Note, that since pipe reads and writes of less then or equal to `PIPE_BUF` are atomic, the pointers get written and read in one shot. One can even have multiple worker threads writing pointers into the same pipe because of the atomicity guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the best way to do this is different for each platform. The canonical, portable way to do it is to have your I/O thread block in `poll`. If you need to get the I/O thread to leave `poll`, you send a single byte on a `pipe` that the thread is polling. That will cause the thread to exit from `poll` immediately.

On Linux, `epoll` is the best way. On BSD-derived operating systems (including OSX, I think), `kqueue`. On Solaris, it used to be `/dev/poll` and there's something else now whose name I forget.

You may just want to consider using a library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). They give you the best I/O model on each platform they support.

Answer (score 3):

Your second approach is the cleaner way to go. It's totally normal to have things like `select` or `epoll` include custom events in your list. This is what we do on my current project to handle such events.  We also use timers (on Linux `timerfd_create`) for periodic events.

On Linux the `eventfd` lets you create such arbitrary user events for this purpose -- thus I'd say it is quite accepted practice. For POSIX only functions, well, hmm, perhaps one of the pipe commands or `socketpair` I've also seen.

Busy-polling is not a good option. First you'll be scanning memory which will be used by other threads, thus causing CPU memory contention. Secondly you'll always have to return to your `select` call which will create a huge number of system calls and context switches which will hurt overall system performance.